# Read 5 million records and finally update a column

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net

I have to update **5 million+ records** in a Database for a table T1. This is a `C# tool` which will `READ (Select)` a column in the table T1, say, `T1.col1`, then extract a value based on a logic from that column and finally have to `UPDATE` another column `T1.col2` in the same table with this processed value and update the Db.

Wanted some opinions on the best/optimised way to achieve this in C# / ADO.NET ?

> NOTE: The extraction logic cannot be part of SQL. That logic is
>   embedded in a COM DLL which I am interoping from .NET and applying on
>   the column Col1's value to generate a new value which has to be finally saved in T1.Col2.

Comment: If you can convert the logic into a SQL expression, you should be able to do this with one UPDATE statement.

Comment: You'll probably wait longer on the update to the col2 fields to complete than the calculations on col2 will take.

Comment: cdhowie - Can you please elaborate ? The extraction logic cannot be part of SQL. THat logic is embedde din a COM DLL which I am interoping from .NET and applying on the column value to generate a new value.

Comment: @cdhow agreed. Best thing would be to keep this on the server, use an SP. Any C# logic will cost enormously.

Comment: @Henk - Not possible. Please see my comment.

Comment: @sees then you're gonna pay. But please specify: Do you need _all_ col1 values before you can set the col2's ?  Row by row would be more attractive.

Comment: If you can't use a single UPDATE statement then I wouldn't expect it to finish in under two days... and I would wager on a much longer duration.

Comment: I cannot use it in SQL. That is for sure. I need to use the Col1 value, apply the COM/Interop logic on the values and then update the corresponding Col2 with those new values.

Comment: @SeeSharp Can you give a code example of what you are doing with the interoped dll so we can get a judge of how simple/complex of operations are happening between the select and update?

Comment: if your stuck with the dll, can you use it as an extended stored procedure? This will be deprecated in future version but will work until then. This way it will stay native and stay on the server. Both big performance boosts.

Comment: Scott - Col1 (nText type) contains binary data, I will deserialize the data, extract the value and then update the Table - Col2 with this value. The Deserialization and Extraction logic are in a COM DLL which I am interoping from C#. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to transfer tha data for some operation by a COM object this is what I would do:

Use a machine with lots of memory - Load the data in chunks (for example 5000 or 50000 rows at a time) into memory, process it and do the update on the SQL Server...

For the UPDATE part use transactions and put 5000 - 20000 UPDATEs into one transaction...

**[EDIT]**: by partitioning the work properly and assigning for 500000 or 1000000 rows to one "worker-machine" you can speed this up to the max limit of your SQL Server... **[/EDIT]**

Another option - though not recommended (only because of theoretically possible security and/or stability issues introduced by the COM object in this specific case):

*Though this is a desciption regarding SQL Server something similar is possible with Oracle on Windows too*

You can put the logic of this transformation into your SQL Server by writing+installing a .NET assembly which exposes a Stored Procedure you can call to do the transformation... the .NET assembly in turn access that COM object... for a howto see http://www.sqlteam.com/article/writing-clr-stored-procedures-in-charp-introduction-to-charp-part-1

The MSDN reference link to this is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Comment: Yahia - 1st option sounds feasible. Why is the 2nd option not recommended ?

Comment: the second option is usually very nice and recommended - but in your specific case it means you need to install that COM object on the DB server... this could create security (and sometimes stability) issues depending on the specific COM object... as long as your COM object is really stable and security is covered go for it... updated my answer accordingly :-)

Comment: Ok, installation of COM object on DB Server won't be possible at all.

Comment: then go with the first option - if you partition the work properly you can have several machines working on this in parallel, just assign every machine 500000 or 1000000 rows to process...

Comment: I did not get what you meant by 'machine' ?

Comment: I mean if you want to speed this up further you would run the conversion process (with the COM object) on multiple computers in parallel, you only need to make sure that every computer has a different subset assigned for processing

Answer (score 0):

By far the *fastest* way would be to perform the update in the SQL code itself:

```
UPDATE T1
SET col2 = [some function based on col1]
```

(Be aware that depending on the database platform, this could explode the transaction log. For MS SQL, specifically, I'd recommend you update in smaller batches, maybe 100k rows or less at a time)

If the function logic is too convoluted for that, then make sure you are issuing all your 5 million updates based on the primary key:

```
UPDATE T1
SET col2 = @newval
WHERE tableID = @id
```

Comment: The extraction logic cannot be part of SQL. That logic is embedde din a COM DLL which I am interoping from .NET and applying on the column value to generate a new value.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of data to have in memory all at once. I would recommend if possible to pull the data in smaller batches of records from the COM DLL and process them. Using [PLinq to objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) would allow you to maximize processor usage. Between the two you should be able to find a happy medium that works well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to update col2 with the new value?

If every row gets the smmae value I would write it into a seperate table with 1 row and just cross join that row in when you need to return the result.

like this:

```
update t2 
set col2 = 1234 -- the computed value over all rows in t1

select t1.col1, 
       t2.col2 
from   t1
       cross join t2 -- t2 only has 1 row
```

Updates are relatively expensive, and writing 1 row is defenitely much cheaper than writing 5 million.

Else I would put the mill where the wood is, so use TSQL if possible. Then again 5 million is not that big of a problem, can you process them on the server or do you need to drag them accross the network? In the last case it does add up.

Rgds Gert-Jan

Comment: Yes, I have to update Col2, hence I asked this question. I know its going to be tough, so I am asking for an optimal / elegant solution in C# / ADO.NET

Comment: ok i see now, though it was 1 value over all rows. Try to tun your code on the server and look at the task manager to see where the bottle neck is (processor or disk). Also, maybe this will probably be fastest using an oldschool oledb cursor where you read, compute and update one row then move to the next. Any native coders in your shop? The old guys will know how to do oledb, and it will save on switching back and forth between .net and native code because the dll is native.

Comment: another tip to speed it up: try to let the server disks do contiguous read/ writes. one way to do that is to split the table in two, where col2 is moved to a seperate table on another filegroup on another disk than col1. That way you can read continuously on one disk, compute the value and write continuously on the other. The keys would be in the same order so sql can use a merge join to get the result you want, that join costs very little to execute. The result table would be a view over these two tables, this technique is called vertical partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

When performing these operations, do you want user to wait until they end? Or can you run this task in background? Maybe even nightly during some scheduled processing? If the latter is true, you can live with your approach and simply perform all your millions of updates, just make sure you do not make user wait for the opertaion to complete. Otherwise, you really need to think off a way to port all update logic into the database.

So depending on the requirements, the options would be:

1) Start a separate thread (or even several threads) to perform updates, while the main thread would return to the user something like "Lengthy operation is runnig. Please come back to this page later to see it's status"

2) Run the updates nightly in a separate process

3) Reorganize the project so that you can afford updates to be performed in the database.

**UPDATE**

I see you constantly saying that you cannot port your update logic into the database. If you are not responsible for the project architecture, could you influence the management to reorganize the whole stuff? It looks like a poor architecture, if such operations are needed.

Comment: Michael, its an upgrade tool which needs to be run once at the client's Database due to some legacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic pointers:

1. Use a DataReader, not a DataSet.  The memory overhead of a DataSet will probably make trouble with this many rows
2. If possible, run the computation portion in several threads in parallel.  You can do that using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for that, but because you are using a COM component there may be some concerns with accessing it from multiple threads.  Consult a COM expert (or open another SO question) on how to determine whether your COM component is thread safe.
3. Do not keep a single massive transaction open while computing the result.  Use the "with(nolock)" hint if appropriate for your semantics.  This will help to prevent your tasks from impacting other readers/writers.

Comment: Computation won't be time consuming. My primary concern is  SELECT and UPDATE parts. Col1 (nText type) contains binary data. I will deserialize the data, extract the value and then update the Table - Col2 with this value. The Deserialization and Extraction logic are in a COM DLL which I am interoping from C#

Comment: In this case it sounds like an embarrassingly parallel problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel.  If you run this as a series of parallel processes, you are likely going to be limited by I/O speed on your SQL server disks and network bandwidth between the SQL server and the application servers.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time deal, then dump your 5 million + records to a file.  Run the logic against the file to generate the new records.  The dump and file logic should be fast and not that time consuming.  Then BULK insert the updated data into a staging table.

At that point, deprecate the previous table and make the staging table the real table with some DDL statements to put in the appropriate indexes, FKs, etc.

That would be the fastest way to handle this amount of records.  Anything else and its probably going to take at least a few days to process everything.